# Saving a Form with Custom Button

Tags: nodes, forms

I am trying to create a custom button that modifies a field in a form then saves the form in the same way as the default save button. The following code creates the button but I am having trouble finding where/how to perform the operation that clicking the default save button executes, with validation and updating every field before executing my submit code.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {


     if ($form_id == 'submission_node_form') {
         $form['actions']['final_submit'] = array(
            '#type'   => 'submit',
            '#value'  => t('Submit'),
            '#submit' => array('mymodule_form_final_submit')
         );
     }  

}

function mymodule_form_final_submit($form, &$form_state) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is calling [drupal_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7)  in your custom module

```
function mymodule_form_final_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  drupal_form_submit('submission_node_form', $form_state);

}
```